# WPF TreeView With List

Tags: wpf, list, treeview

Im new to WPF and come to a problem.
I have to implement a GUI for a model.
In this model there are brackets, documents, sheets and images.
Each bracket can hold more brackets or documents. Each document can hold sheets. Each sheet has image. Each element holds the child elements in a list.
So a bracket has a list of brackets and documents, documents a list of sheets ...
So I have an HierarchicalDataTemplate for this structure and it works.

But now i want to edit the data (move or delete some items) I have no idea how to tell the tree to update.

I now the ObservableCollection and I use these for the root brackets (because its no problem to get them in there) but I dont want to go through each bracket and each document and each sheet and make every List on my way to an ObservableCollection.

Can I notify my tree about the changes let's say in a sheet List?

My View (not all but the important things)

```
   <DockPanel.Resources>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Bracket}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type m:Document}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sheets}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:Sheet}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Images}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:IPSImage}">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Width="150" Margin="0,5,0,0"></Image>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </DockPanel.Resources>

  <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
     <Button Command="{Binding OpenAllCommand}">Alle Öffnen</Button>
     <Button Command="{Binding MoveItemUpCommand}">Nach Oben</Button>
  </ToolBar>

  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Brackets}" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
           <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ExpandTreeViewItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        </Style>
     </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
           <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"></cmd:EventToCommand>
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </TreeView>
```

ViewModel:

// Each bracket creates new documents and each document creates new sheets in the constructor

```
private ObservableCollection<Bracket> m_Brackets;
      public TreeViewModel()
      {
         m_Brackets = new ObservableCollection<Bracket>();
         m_Brackets.Add(new Bracket());
         if (m_Brackets[0] != null)
         {
            m_Brackets[0].Brackets.Add(new Bracket(m_Brackets[0].Id));
         }
         m_Brackets.Add(new Bracket());
      }
```

So when I remove a sheet in the m_Brackets/Documents nothing happens.
I try to call RaisePropertyChanged("Sheets") but nothing.

When I call Tree.Items.Refresh() all is fine but I think that's no possibility or?

Thanks for every Help
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tree to update itself then you have no choice but to use ObservableCollections throughout.

Your `RaisePropertyChanged("Sheets")` is being ignored because WPF is smart enough to compare the object reference to see if it really has changed. You don't mention how you are storing the sheet etc collections, but in order to see any update using your manual property changed event, you'd have to swap out the entire collection for a new one.

Comment: Thank you

I will try to implement all with an ObservableCollection.
I thinks its the easiest (and maybe only) way to do it.

Thanks for help